# In Spring Batch, getting out of memory Exception to the overriden Write method of implemented Writer class for the specific scenario

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration, batch-processing

In Spring Batch I'm appending each chunk of data to a StringBuilder in the overriden Write method of implemented writer class and in afterStep encrypting full payload(String Builder) of data 
and writing to a file. As I'm appending each chuck of data to String Builder , getting out of memory Exception or heap size issue as the record size is huge and keep on appending to StringBuilder,Please
suggest what's is best way to get out of the situation(My intention is not to encrypt and write to a file with each chunk of records)

Concerened Code:

```
  public class XXXXXFileWriter<T> implements ItemWriter<String>
    {

    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    @Override
        public void write(List<? extends String> items) throws Exception {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Iterator<String> iterator = (Iterator<String>) items.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String value = (String) doSomeBasicLogicalStuffs(new GenericMessage<String>(iterator.next()));
                if (sb.length() > 0) {
                    sb.append(working with some business logic with the String value); // here getting out of memory exception while keep on appending the chunks of records
                } else {
                    sb.append(value);
                }
            }
        }

        @AfterStep
        public void WriteFullPayloadToFile() throws Exception {
                // Encrypting and file writing procees does here.Our encryption method can accept InputSteam. to the StringBuilder we are converting to InputStream and passing to encryption method.
                }
        }

    }
```

Please suggest me with best Spring Batch approach for this kind of scenarios.

Comment: Doing that in memory is a bad idea you shouldn't do that because, as you noticed, will run into problems. Also you should also separate your processing and writing. Create an `ItemProcessor` which does the processing and an `ItemWriter` which only writes. You really want/need to write the chunks out to file and not from an in-memory string. You want to keep your memory as low as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should encrypt on-the-fly as you write to the file - not separately encrypted chunks, use an outputstream and keep writing to it.

Use Bouncy Castle or similar.